# trouble merging a couple of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

i need to merge two dataframes but i can't get output that makes sense to me. i have tried using left and full joins but both have problems.

one of these dataframes, `main`, contains information about provider characteristics and the other, `parquet`, contains information about whether a provider was affected by a certain policy. i need to merge them in order to do some analytical work.

i have a stata file called `main` that looks like this after reading it into r using `foreign`.

```
year    prov_id tech_1 teach beds nonprof govt
1 2007  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1
2 2010  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1
3 2001  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1
4 2005  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1
5 2002  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1
6 2004  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1
```

and i have a parquet file called `parquet` which contains information about whether `prov_id` received `treat` that looks like this after reading it into r using `arrow`.

```
prov_id    treat `__index_level_0__`
  <chr>   <dbl>               <int>
1 11z111      0                   0
2 11z113      0                   1
3 11z132      0                   2
4 11z135      0                   3
5 11z13z      0                   4
6 11z142      0                   5
```

after doing a left join (`left_join(main, parquet, by = 'prov_id')`), all values for `treat` are `NA` instead of `0` or `1`. i don't understand why this is happening. could it be related to the types of data that i'm working with? i have never worked with a parquet file before. this seems like it may not be relevant because r has turned both files into dataframes and i think that should make them compatible.

```
year    prov_id tech_1 teach beds nonprof govt treat __index_level_0__
1 2007  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1    NA                NA
2 2010  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1    NA                NA
3 2001  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1    NA                NA
4 2005  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1    NA                NA
5 2002  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1    NA                NA
6 2004  11Z111      0     0   35       0    1    NA                NA
```

i think one of the issues may be that there are different numbers of unique `prov_id` values in the two datasets, so producing some `NA` values may be inevitable, but i don't think the whole `treat` variable should consist only of `NA`s.

```
> length(unique(parquet$prov_id))
[1] 1305
> length(unique(main$prov_id))
[1] 2132
```

i have also tried using a full join (i called the file i created using this type of join `p` for simplicity) and the results are a bit different.

not all of the `treat` values are `NA`, but most of them are, and the number of `NA`s is the same as the number of observations in `main`. also, the numbers of `0`s and `1`s in `p` are the same as the numbers of these values in `parquet`.

another thing i should add that is kind of hard for me to show here is that when `treat` isn't `NA` in `p`, the values for all other variables except `prov_id` are. this means i can't use `p` to estimate the relationships between `treat` and any of the other variables.

```
> table(p$treat, useNA = 'ifany')

    0     1  <NA> 
 1278    27 13050 

> table(parquet$treat)

   0    1 
1278   27 

> nrow(main)
[1] 13050
```

one last issue: i am not sure what `__index_level_0__` in `parquet` is supposed to represent. it's a 0 indexed sequence of numbers that counts the rows in this dataset, so maybe it was just included by mistake. but maybe it's supposed to represent a year variable? i'm not sure.

any advice for how i can get this working? i have tried other types of joins, but the results are even worse (0 observations). i need to get this data merged properly so that i can use it to estimate some statistical models, but my output so far is unusable.

thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Have you considered that the 'z' in `prov_id` in parquet is lower case? You could use `toupper()` on this column and see if that works.

Comment: @William, thank you for pointing that out! no, i did not notice that at first. it appears that my data is properly merged now with a left join after dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parquet$prov_id <- toupper(parquet$prov_id)` to get uppercase Z in `parquet` as commented by William. Here is how:

```
library(tidyverse)

main <- tribble(
~year,    ~prov_id, ~tech_1, ~teach, ~beds, ~nonprof, ~govt,
"2007", "11Z111", 0, 0, 35, 0, 1, 
"2010", "11Z111", 0, 0, 35, 0, 1, 
"2001", "11Z111", 0, 0, 35, 0, 1, 
"2005", "11Z111", 0, 0, 35, 0, 1, 
"2002", "11Z111", 0, 0, 35, 0, 1, 
"2004", "11Z111", 0, 0, 35, 0, 1)


parquet <- tribble(
  ~prov_id,   ~treat, ~`__index_level_0__`,
"11z111", 0, 0,
"11z113", 0, 1, 
"11z132", 0, 2,
"11z135", 0, 3, 
"11z13z", 0, 4, 
"11z142", 0, 5) 

parquet$prov_id <- toupper(parquet$prov_id)

df_joined <- main %>% 
  full_join(parquet, by="prov_id")
```

[image]